# multiple build targets for android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have developed an android app using specific resources (images,sounds.. e.t.c). Now I want to 'customize' the app by using different versions of the resources but with the same names. Now i normally do this by replacing the old res folder with the new one containing the resources and rebuilding the project. Is there an easier way of doing this? I'm not so familiar with build configurations and ant hence my question. Any links would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a Unix variant, you can play with symlinks. Don't know about Windows.

Note that if you want to publish the two apps on the android market as two different apps, they also need to have different root package pathes.